# Where can I find Google+ code repository?

Tags: open-source, closures, google-code, google-plus

First, is Google+ project open source? I readed some time ago that google+ is entirely written in google closure and I would like to ponderate a real big enterprise implementation of closure as could be google+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google+ is not open source. Google provides a number of APIs that provide developers with access to a subset of Google+ features and there are "client libraries" (libraries written in a variety of programming languages) for using these APIs. Many of the client libraries are open source. Google+, itself, is not open source however. As to your question about Closure, you should keep in mind that Google+ consists of both the user interface that you see in your browser as well as server-side code that processes and stores this data... moreover, there is more to the UI than just JavaScript (e.g. CSS and HTML), so even if all of the JavaScript in the UI used Closure... there would still be plenty of other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can Check [The following link](http://code.google.com/). There you can find a lot about google products and open source packages and programs.